# Navigate to an external URL from CRM 2015 form

Tags: dynamics-crm, microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-crm-online, dynamics-crm-2015

Do we have a supported way to navigate to an external URL (Payment Gateway, another application) from CRM 2015 form in the same tab/window?  
We would also need the script to be compatible with all the browsers and devices. I have also tried my luck using `window.location.redirect`, `window.location.replace`, `window.location.href`, `showModalDialog`, so on. The redirect URL is always appended with my CRM organization's URL.
These are anyway unsupported in CRM 2015 as per [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-in/library/gg328483.aspx).  
Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: It makes no sense to downvote the question without proper justification as I have tried my level best to find the best solution with all the possible combinations. Many of the commands listed above works with CRM 2011 and even 2013 but not in 2015.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the built in form customization to add a navigation link.  Simply go into the CRM Form customization, click on "Navigation" on the ribbon, and then click on the Insert tab of the Ribbon and Click on Navigation Link.  You can then edit the Navigation Link Properties and give it a name, change the icon if you wish, and specify the External URL you wish to navigate to.  Then save and publish the customizations.  If you wish to use something from the current record to dynamically build a URL to put in this Navigation Link, the solution given on this page should still work in CRM 2015 even though it was originally written for CRM 2011 - http://www.crmanswers.net/2013/03/dynamic-navigation-links-using.html .

Answer (score 1):

It seems like opening an external page in the same tab/window is not supported by CRM 2015. I had to use `window.open` to open the page in a seperate tab/window and is supported by all the browsers.